# Bash Script does nothing

Tags: bash, terminal

I am trying to create a shell script i can run from anywhere in the terminal,

the script simply echoes a message

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Excellent work Snake!"
```

I changed the scripts permissions with

```
chmod 775 test.sh
```

the script is in my documents, i made a symbolic link to /usr/bin with

```
ln -s ./test.sh /usr/bin
```

when i run the script from home for example, instead of the message echoing, nothing happens, e.g.

```
babbleshack@babbleshack ~ $ test
babbleshack@babbleshack ~ $
```

am i failing to understand something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test` is a bash [builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-test) - called with no arguments, as in your example, it does nothing<sup>1</sup>.

Your shell script is not called `test` but `test.sh`, so to run it you need to type:

```
$ test.sh
```

However, that's not the only problem. Your command `ln -s ./test.sh /usr/bin` isn't doing quite what you think - `./test.sh` is a relative path, and links to relative paths are relative to the location of the link, **not** relative to where you were when you typed the command.

You actually want something like:

```
$ ln -s /home/babbleshack/test.sh /usr/bin
```

... at which point things ought to work.

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically, it *unsuccessfully* does nothing (in other words, it returns a non-zero error code). If that means nothing to you, don't worry - it's not important for the purposes of this answer.

Comment: when i run test.sh i get command not found error.
I am going to try renaming my script

Comment: I renamed my file to foo.sh made a link and i am getting a 'command not found' error

Comment: @Babbleshack that probably means your `ln -s ./test.sh /usr/bin` failed ... do you see an entry for `/usr/bin/test.sh` if you type `ls -l /usr/bin/te*`?

Comment: @Babbleshack are you sure that you successfully made the link? What's in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: yer its there i ran ls | grep testme in /usr/bin and it shows the link

Comment: No ... use `ls -l /usr/bin/te*`. There's a reason I'm suggesting this.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      11 Aug 17 22:33 /usr/bin/testme.sh -> ./testme.sh

Comment: its there i ran that command from home dir

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10181/discussion-between-zero-piraeus-and-babbleshack)

Comment: try `$bash test.sh`

Comment: Also check that $PATH conatins /usr/bin